# Recursion in finding the height of the tree-what values will be returned to the values that are assigned to recursive calls?

Tags: c++, c, recursion, tree

```
int height(struct node *root)
{
    struct node *temp;
    int ld=-1,rd=-1;

    if(root!=NULL)
    {
        ld=height(root->left);
        rd=height(root->right);

        if(ld>rd)
            return (ld+1);
        else
            return (rd+1);
    }
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Can anyone explain how the local variables ld,rd get incremented and prints the height of the tree.

Comment: Draw a small but non-trivial tree and walk through it with the program on paper

Comment: I think you should learn the art of "dry run".

Answer (score 2):

[image]
See, your program uses recursion. it calculates the depth of both the left and the right parts and then checks which of these is greater. Since, the total depth of the tree will be (1 + ld or rd) whichever is greater.
It basically goes from 1 level to another, till the time it reaches `NULL` ie the end of the tree.
Basically, the function is trivial in itself and doesn't need much explanation.
I am giving a pseudo-code for the above function, which can help you:-

```
    maxDepth()
    1. If tree is empty then return 0
    2. Else
      (a) Get the max depth of left subtree recursively  i.e., 
          call maxDepth( tree->left-subtree)
      (a) Get the max depth of right subtree recursively  i.e., 
          call maxDepth( tree->right-subtree)
      (c) Get the max of max depths of left and right 
          subtrees and add 1 to it for the current node.
          max_depth = max(max dept of left subtree,  
                         max depth of right subtree) 
                         + 1
       (d) Return max_depth`
```